# Why Can I No Longer Add Shortcuts to Start in Windows 10 after Updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, windows-10-v1607

Recently my computer updated its version of Windows 10 (Update:1607 or Anniversary Update).  A few things have changed most notable the notification system and the start menu.

Whilst looking at the start menu I noticed that one of my shortcuts had disappeared.  So I tried to re-add it by

1. right clicking and clicking 'pin to start' this did not add the
   shortcut but did change 'pin to start' to 'unpin from start'.
2. Next I tried dragging the shortcut into the start menu however, it
   does not allow me to and the mouse changes to a red cross.

The shortcut is to the .exe file from eclipse.  So I was wondering if anyone had run into this problem and knew how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it.  One day I logged on and the start menu was huge.  Then when i tried to add it worked and i could re-size the menu to the normal size again.  So maybe it was just a bug and it thought there was no room for the icon when there was.  If anyone else has this problem just try resizing the start menu and it may work.